# Haskell : Infinite list when integer is pushed to stack implementation

Tags: haskell, stack

I'm trying to implement a simple Stack but I'm confused as to why I get an infinite list when I push an integer to the stack.

All of the other functions work as I expect them but I don't understand the problem with `push`. It goes wrong when I try to assign an empty stack to itself that has pushed a variable like the following:

```
λ > a = makeStack
λ > push 3 a
[3]
λ > a
[]
λ > a = push 3 a
λ > a
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3^CInterrupted.
```

```
type Stack a = [a]

makeStack :: Stack a 
makeStack = []

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push a as = (a:as)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell does not allow mutation. In a source file, if you define a variable `a` and then attempt to reassign it, as you do here with `a = push 3 a`, you would get a compilation error. The only reason you don't is that you are working in GHCi, which does allow you to redefine variables - this is purely a convenience so you don't have to keep on thinking up new names while experimenting with different definitions.

And, crucially, `a = push 3 a` is *not* giving a new value to `a` based on the previous one, as it would be in an imperative language. Instead, it is a definition of `a` *in terms of itself*.

That's why you get an infinite list - your definition is processed as follows:

```
a = push 3 a
   = 3:a
   = 3:(push 3 a)
   = 3:(3:a)
```

and so on. Because of Haskell's laziness, there's no problem with a definition like this - GHCi will, when you ask for the full list, as here, simply calculate one element at a time, and therefore keep printing 3s until you tell it to stop.

To get what you want, you need to either just type `push 3 a`, or if you need to assign it a name, simply choose a different name from `a`. `b = push 3 a` followed by `b` will behave as you expect.

Comment: I recall that in GHCi (or rather any `do` block) there is a special trick to “reassign” a variable using itself: `a <- pure (push 3 a)`.

Comment: Yes, that would work in a `do` block (if you desugar it, the "new" `a` on the left is the argument to a lambda, and therefore shadows the "old" one) - but it has to be understood that this is very different from normal "assignment" (or rather definition) in Haskell. I am not sure about GHCi allowing that, and will have to try it - I'm aware GHCi implicitly interprets everything as happening in the `IO` monad but I'd be surprised if it allowed a single line with a "left arrow" and nothing following it, as this is meaningless on its own.

Comment: I mentioned that trick just because I saw someone else recommending it, for bindings in `do` is by default non-recursive (with `do rec` explicitly recursive). (The author argues that `let` is by default recursive is unfortunate in Haskell.) I personally believe a single “left arrow” binding should be valid in GHCi without surprise, for otherwise there would be no way to obtain the intermediate result of an IO action, and bind it to a variable for further use.

Answer (score 4):

There are (I guess, almost) no **mutable** (thanks to @amalloy for correcting my terminology) variables in haskell.

If you write something like this:

```
x = f x
```

It enters an infinite loop: `f (f (f ...`

So, there is no *past* value of `a` in which `3` may be pushed.

Therefore, you have to put `push 3 a` in some other value (or directly into the ghci for that matter).

Such a loop might come in handy sometimes though. Take a look at [`Data.Function.fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html):

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

It can be used to do the same thing as you do:

```
GHCi> fix (push 3)
[3,3,3,3,^CInterrupted.
```

Yet, the infinite loop is not always the case. Take a look:

```
factFun rec n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n - 1)
```

This function might look like factorial, yet the recursive call in the non-terminating branch is replaced with a dummy (`rec`). We would like to have this dummy replaced with `factFun` over and over and over again to get the factorial. `fix` does this:

```
GHCi> fix factFun 4
24
```

---

Note: I will duplicate my comment here: if the reader does not know of `fix` yet, I want to invite them on a long and interesting trip. I suggest they start with this [wikibook on denotational semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics).

Comment: That's a really interesting function! I'm going to see if I can use it !

Comment: @JiangShi it is a great function. I suggest you check out [a wikibook on denotational semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) - it speaks a lot of it. That is pretty much where I started. Good luck :).

Comment: There are loads of variables in Haskell. They just aren't mutable.

Comment: @amalloy you are right - sorry for my terminology. I edited the post.